# What measure is this script using when no measure is specified

Tags: ssas, mdx

Ok, so im trying to look at examples on how to use this function, but I still dont get it.  The example on msdn, here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Using AW 2008 as an example, this query

```
       SELECT ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Semester]
       , 3
       , [Date].[Calendar].[Month].[October 2007])
       ON 0

   FROM [Adventure Works]


results:
April 2006
$882,899.94
```

Where is that value coming from?  What measure is this pulling from?

Now, this other example looks a bit more clear.
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3073581_3/MDX-Essentials---MDX-Time-Series-Functions-Part-III-The-LastPeriods-and-ParallelPeriod-Functions.htm

Comment: the answer you marked as the answer does not really agree with the title of this question and answer. Do you understand the function `parrellelperiod` ? Or is your lack of understanding why mdx returns a number when no measure is specified in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be the default measure for the cube, or more precisely the default member for the Measures dimension.

Try this query to see what I mean:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Default Measure] AS
[Measures].DefaultMember.Name
SELECT
[Measures].[Default Measure] On 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

This returns "Reseller Sales Amount" for my version.

Hope that helps,

Ash